# Getting error when using GridSearch with XLNET in multiclassification nlp task

Tags: python, nlp, gridsearchcv

I want to use Grid Search with XLNET for nlp multiclassification task.  This is my code:

```
param_grid = {
  'num_labels': [3, 4],  
  'learning_rate': [2e-5, 3e-5],
  'batch_size': [16, 32],
}

random_seeds = [42, 123, 456]
best_scores = []
best_params = []

for seed in random_seeds:
  print(f"Trying with random seed {seed}")

  torch.manual_seed(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)
  grid_search = GridSearchCV(model_base, param_grid, cv=5, 
  scoring='accuracy')

  # Perform GridSearch on the training and validation data
  grid_search.fit(encoded_inputs_base['input_ids'], train_labels)
```

I want to find the best parameters for my xlnet model trying different seeds. I, however, get the error:

```
TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, 
XLNetForSequenceClassification(
(transformer): XLNetModel(
(word_embedding): Embedding(32000, 768)
(layer): ModuleList(
  (0-11): 12 x XLNetLayer(
    (rel_attn): XLNetRelativeAttention(
      (layer_norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, ...
```

how can I solve it?